# Facebook API, search Groups by keyword returns an empty array

Tags: facebook, keyword, facebook-group

I had a working code here that searched for groups that contain a keyword using Facebook API. Now here's what happened. It all worked for a while, but now it returns an empty array instead of result. Pages search works though. The developer was trying it different ways, but still doesn't work. We've used user token as well as app token ("...|......."). If you have a working code for that, would you mind checking if your code still works searching groups? It suspect it might be related to api change.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone's interested, I've found out it came out to be a recent unresolved bug on FB platform. Here's the thread from support.

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/887849337946944/